# How to give air a texture?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Hello i've been trying to search for a tutorial or anything about **adding air a texture**. I'm currently using Minecraft Windows 10 1.5.2. I would also like to know if it's possible to **add a static semi-transparent image on the first player perspective**.
**I'm trying to achieve something like this:**[image: Detroit: Become Human]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You can't.

Air is not really a block, it's not rendered on its own. It's just the absence of blocks.

Maybe you want to retexture and remodel signs or other blocks without a collision instead. I don't know how that would be similar to your image, but it should do what you asked for.

If you want to display additional information to the player, maybe you want to look into the commands [title](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/title) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/title&oldid=1253234)) or [scoreboard objectives setdisplay](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Objectives_commands) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Scoreboard&oldid=1264571#Objectives_commands)) instead. For something more fancy, [SimplySarc got creative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbdLNsWn7aI).

Comment: Good answer. Similar to what I would have said. Air is *technically* a non-collision, transparent block, but as you said, doesn't render.

Comment: Server-side, it's saved like any other block in the palette, but I didn't want to get overly technical with this explanation, since the asker apparently doesn't have that much knowledge about the inner workings of Minecraft.

Comment: Ah ok. I understand. It is still a good answer though.

Comment: Thank you, i really don't know another place to ask technical stuff like this, my apologies i have minimal acknowledge about this type of stuff. Is there any way to achieve what i asked for, like adding a yellow highlight to entities?
And no, i dont want to display something to the player as what i'm asking for must be client-side. Plus scoreboard is not available on BE yet.

Comment: Firstly, you asked in the right place, everything is ok. Secondly, I don't really know what you are trying to do, since I don't know the game you posted a screenshot of. If you want a static thing that stays in the same location and rotation, you can remodel/retexture a block, if you want something that only one player sees in a fixed spot on the screen, you can use title, scoreboard or SimplySarc's idea. The information you need should all be in my answer.

Comment: Btw, I watched an LP of this game now. What you want is likely some remodeled entity. Or just a sign or chat message.